# Unable to echo the data from ssh execution to webpage in PHP

Tags: php, ssh

I am writing a PHP script where I take input from user like server IP and one more input.

After this is available, I make ssh call to the server and execute some command. I want to show the output on the web page but i gets error as 500 (server error).

Here is my main script where i get input from user:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Centos Health Checker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
<center>
<div id="login-form">
<form method="post" action="redirectPage.php">
<table align="center" width="30%" border="0">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="IP" placeholder="System IP" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="Component" placeholder="Component" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><button type="submit" name="submit">Check System</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my landing page:

```
<?php
function Connect()
{
        include('/home/as5714/php_data/Net/SSH2.php');
        $IP1 = $_POST['IP'];
        $Component1 = $_POST['Component'];

        $ssh = new Net_SSH2($IP1);
        if (!$ssh->login('centos', 'centos')) {
            exit('Login Failed');
        }

        echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
        echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        Connect();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome - <?php echo $IP1; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
 <div id="left">
    <label>cleartuts</label>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
     <div id="content">
         Cennecting to ' <?php echo $IP1; ?>&nbsp; and Data is : <?php echo $data2; ?>&nbsp;<a href="homePage.php">Go Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting server error(500) while using above php code.

Please note that I am working on vim editor on a linux server for the script and do not have any logs available. Also, If I just run the program to do ssh connection and execution of command in server directly (php 123.php), I get proper data on console.

Please help.

Comment: as always with a 500, look at the server's error log for details about the 500. there's no pointing in flailing around in the code trying to figure out where the problem is, when you could just look up what the problem REALLY is.

Comment: Thanks. I enabled the logging and got it to work without throwing 500. But I am only able to print data using echo in my Connect() function. If i do an echo at any other place. I am not getting the data value.

Comment: got it to work by closing function connect() at the end.